# MySql DATETIME to java.util.Calendar

Tags: java, mysql, datetime

I managed in JAVA to store a calendar into a mysql DATETIME field
To fetch this value

```
entry.date = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UT"));
entry.date.setTime(rs.getDate(DBBLogEntries.entDate));
```

Where the entry.date is a java.util.Calendar
In the database the value is this: '2012-07-07 07:18:46'
I store all date values in a unique timezone in the db. ready to make all the extra work required to add or substract hours depending on the country from wich the request is comming.

The problem is that it brings the date but doesn't seem to brinng me the time.
Any sugestion please?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably because Java has a different date format than [`mysql format`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html)(`YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`)

Visit the link :

http://www.coderanch.com/t/304851/JDBC/java/Java-date-MySQL-date-conversion

You may use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) as follows.

```
java.util.Date dt = new java.util.Date();

java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = 
     new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

String dateTime = sdf.format(dt);
```

Comment: I succesfully already inserted the date in the db. The problem is when i try to fetch it from the db.

Comment: Where are you displaying date Servlet, JSP, JSTL/EL, JSF or so? If you're simply dealing with `ResultSet` then you can use [`ResultSet.getDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getDate%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Yes I am sorry. rs is a ResultSet and i am calling rs.getdate("datefield"); The problem is the time component is missing.

Comment: Then you should use [`ResultSet.getTimestamp()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getTimestamp%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: This is finally what I did. fetched the field as rs.getstring and convert to calendar using simpledateformat. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You should read a `timestamp` from the `ResultSet` object.

```
java.sql.Timestamp ts = rs.getTimestamp( DBBLogEntries.entDate );
```

Which returns a `Timestamp` instance that includes date and time.

Answer (score 0):

don't use Java.util.Date ,use the Java.sql.Date.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the MySql DATE type? This does **not** preserve the time component.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html

Alternatively how are you retrieving the date from the db?

Comment: Select entrydate from table where...... (entrydate is a DATETIME type field in the db)

Comment: Ok. Please show the code where you are persisting the date. How are you setting the parameter?

Comment: insert into tablename (entrydate, .....) values ('2012-07-07 07:18:46')... The field is a DATETIME type and the table looks fine. The truth is that i define static clasess with static strings that contains the table and column names (Is just a practise) But the insertion looks to work fine. Note that i use parametrized queries in case of strings so the real values clause looks like "VALUES (?).

Comment: You want to set the parameter as a java.sql.Date and not as a string object. Let your jdbc driver figure what it needs to do to persist it.